# Is a diffeomorphism always maps the set of (Jordan) measure zero to the set of (Jordan) measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-measure, diffeomorphism

> Let $\phi: D_t\to
>   D_x$ be a diffeomorphism of an open set $D_t\subset \mathbb{R}^n$
> onto a set $D_x \subset \mathbb{R}^n
> $ of the same type. Then the following assertions hold.

> a) If $E_t\subset D_t$ is a set of (Lebesgue) measure zero, its image $\phi(E_t) \subset D_x$
> is also a set of measure zero.

> b)If a set $E_t$ contained in $D_t$
> along with its closure $\bar E_t$
> has Jordan measure
> zero, its image $\phi(E_t) = E_x $ is contained in $D_x$ along with its closure and also
> has (Jordan) measure zero.

> c) If a (Jordan) measurable set $E_t$
> is contained in the domain $D_t$
> along with its closure $\bar E_t$, its image $E_x = \phi(E_t)$ is Jordan measurable and $\bar E_x \subset D_x$.

The lemma above is from $\S$11.5 of *Mathematical Analysis* by Zorich. The proof of the lemma based on the fact that every open subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$
can be represented as the union of a countable number of closed intervals (no two of
which have any interior points in common).

According to a) we can conclude that:  a diffeomorphism maps the set of (Lebesgue) measure zero to the set of (Lebesgue) measure zero.

In b) and c) the Lemma restrict the set $E_t$ to satisfying $\bar E_t\subset D_t$.

But I wanna know if b) and  c) still holds for sets $E_t$ that $\bar E_t$ is not subset of $D_t$($D_t\setminus \bar E_t\neq \varnothing$)? So that we can say : a diffeomorphism maps the set of (Jordan) measure zero to the set of (Jordan) measure zero, and maps a Jordan measurable set to a Jordan measurable set. I guess this is not true, so could you give a **counterexample**, where a  diffeomorphism maps a set of (Jordan) measure zero to a set **not** of (Jordan) measure zero ,or maps a Jordan measurable set to a Jordan unmeasurable set?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, both your questions have an answer of YES, since the continuous image of a compact set is compact and the continuous image of an $F_{\sigma}$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set (the second result follows by using the fact that in ${\mathbb R}^n$ we have $F_{\sigma}$ equivalent to $\sigma$-compact, and the fact that functions preserve unions). The part about $F_{\sigma}$ sets is not needed if your definition of "Jordan measurable set" requires the set to be bounded.

Comment: @Dave L.Renfro The Jordan measure zero requires covers of finite number of unions instead of countable number,  so take b) for example, we can only say that in every union $ I_i, $ $E\cap I_i$ is Jordan measure zero,but countable union of set of Jordan measure zero doesn't necessarily be a set of Jordan measure zero. I can't understand, if we don't use $\bar E\subset D$, how can we get the conclusion?

Comment: Let $E$ (be bounded and) have Jordan measure zero. Then $\bar{E}$ is compact and has Lebesgue measure zero, hence the image of $\bar{E}$ is compact and has Lebesgue measure zero, hence the image of $E$ has Jordan measure zero (since that image is contained in a closed Lebesgue measure zero set). I'm using a standard equivalence (definition in some books, theorem in other books) that a set has Jordan measure zero if and only if its closure (is bounded and) has Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: @Dave L.Renfro:So you have already used the $\bar E\subset D$ when you consider the image of$\bar E$ ? And what I wanna ask is what if $\bar E$ is not in D, so we can't talk about the image of it.

Comment: Probably someone more familiar with Zorich's book and possible subtleties with multivariable functions can help, because I'm not sure whether there could be something I'm overlooking involving the notion of "Jordan measure zero" when the ambient space is an arbitrary open set as compared to the notion of "Jordan measure zero" when the ambient space is ${\mathbb R}^n.$

Comment: @Dave: I think the ambient space makes no difference, I totaly agree with your solution,but what I mean is $\bar E $ may beyond the domain of $\phi$ so we may unable to consider $\phi(\bar E)$.Thanks anyway!